# Problem building C++ code with Eigen3 and CMake eigen3/Eigen/Core' file not found

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen3

I have simple C++ project that is organized like this:

```
project
|-- Input
|     |-- data.cpp          <-- this file used eigen3
|     |--- CmakeLists.txt
|--- main.cpp
|--- CmakeLists.txt
```

Basically I am trying to create .so library from input and have main.cpp calls functions in it.
CMake under project looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(myProj)

find_package (Eigen3 REQUIRED)

# Dependencies paths
set(EIGEN_INC_DIR  ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})

if (TARGET Eigen3::Eigen)
  message("Eigen was found").  <--- I do see this message so Eigen3 package is found
endif (TARGET Eigen3::Eigen) 
add_subdirectory(Input)
<more cmake commands to link with main.cpp>
```

CMake under Input looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
set(TARGET_LIB_INPUT input_data)

set(SRC_FILES
    Data.cpp
)

set(INC_DIRS
    ${EIGEN_INC_DIR}
)

include_directories(${INC_DIRS})

add_library (${TARGET_LIB_INPUT} SHARED ${SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries (${TARGET_LIB_INPUT} Eigen3::Eigen)
```

in file data.cpp, I do the following include to eigen3

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>
```

But I keep getting the error
fatal error: 'eigen3/Eigen/Core' file not found
I see the build command clearly include eigen directory:
-I /usr/local/include/eigen3

Anybody knows what am I missing here?
Thanks for help

Comment: Let's see. You have a directory named `/usr/local/include/eigen3`, and then you want to find a file named `eigen3/Eigen/Core` inside that directory. Do you really have a file named `/usr/local/include/eigen3/eigen3/Eigen/Core` on your machine?

Comment: OTOH *if* your compiler looks inside `/usr/local/include` by default (which is usually the case), and *if* there is a file named `/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core`, then `#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>` should have found it without needing any extra `-I` command line switches. So you may want to check that these things do indeed hold.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Indeed I don't need to include eigen3 directory.
I removed the include from CMakeLists.txt inside Input directory. 
I now see the following in build command 
`
-isystem /usr/local/include/eigen3
`
But build still fails with same error.
Yes there is file eigen3/Eigen/Core

Comment: `#include <Eigen/Core>`.  The `eigen3` prefix is already added to the search path because of the `target_link_libraries()` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The include directory defined in `Eigen3::Eigen` already includes `eigen3` (e.g., `/usr/include/eigen3` on Ubuntu). So you should use `#include <Eigen/Core>`.

You can check this by:

```
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED CONFIG)

# checking property of the target
get_target_property(inc_dir Eigen3::Eigen INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message("[DEBUG] inc_dir: ${inc_dir}")

# or checking the Eigen variable
message("[DEBUG] EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

`EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS` is defined in [here](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/3af8c262acdfb50fbfc88e6c640d5d1a582145a9/cmake/Eigen3Config.cmake.in#L17).